# Questions on Topic filters in azure service bus

Tags: service, bus

Couldn't find any articles answering this specific question so here goes.

Say you have a topic called companyorders and you have 3 filters/subscriptions, companyA, companyB and allcompanies.

Messages sent to the topic for companyA get passed to sub companyA and allcompanies etc.  Then messages start coming in for a companyC that hasn't got a specific sub setup so they are sent to only allcompanies sub.

When companyC starts up their client app and it creates the companyC sub(I don't see a way of setting up a sub with a specific filter in the portal) how or can I pull messages from the allcompanies sub for companyC that where previously missed because the sub was not setup beforehand?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the subscription/filter needs to be setup before messages are sent to the topic.  I tested this by creating a topic and a subscription.  I then posted messages to the topic with property DriverID. I passed in a DriverID = 1.  This message ended up in the subscription setup earlier as this subscription has the 'MatchAll' filter by default.

I then created another subscription with a filter of DriverID = 1.  When I posted a message to the topic and set the property DriverId = 1 it got sent to the 2 subscriptions as expected.  Messages posted before this subscription was setup that had DriverID = 1 were not automatically moved to the new subscription that matches the filter.

Paul